# Flask and scaling and concurrency

Tags: python, concurrency, flask

In the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/becomingbig/#scale-like-a-pro) I see the following:

> There is only one limiting factor regarding scaling in Flask which are
>   the context local proxies. They depend on context which in Flask is
>   defined as being either a thread, process or greenlet. If your server
>   uses some kind of concurrency that is not based on threads or
>   greenlets, Flask will no longer be able to support these global
>   proxies. However the majority of servers are using either threads,
>   greenlets or separate processes to achieve concurrency which are all
>   methods well supported by the underlying Werkzeug library.

My question: What other concurrent mechanisms are there other than these 3 methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pretty interesting concurrency mechanism is the asynchronous model. You have a single process with a single thread running the whole show, with all the I/O or otherwise lengthy tasks being asynchronous and callback based. This method scales really well for I/O bound services, servers in this category easily handle the [C10K](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) problem.

See [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) or [node.js](http://nodejs.org) for examples.

Comment: That is basically covered by greenlet.

Comment: @Jahaja: No. Greenlet based web servers are one thing, asynchronous (event driven) web servers like Tornado are another thing. They both achieve a similar goal of higher concurrency, but they get there using different methods. In particular, Flask can work on top of a greenlet based web server, but it won't adapt easily to an asynchronous server.

Comment: My point is that both solutions use what you describe in lower layers. Gevent using libevent/libev and node.js using libuv. (remember reading somewhere that gevent 2.0, if released, may be based on libuv.)

Comment: The question is about concurrency models, not use of low level  libraries. The fact is that Gevent is in a completely different category than Node.js and Tornado.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. Just wanted to note that most of what you wrote in this answer applies to greenlet/gevent as well.